How to conditionally install modules using pip with pyproject.toml?
I'm trying to set different user-versions inside the same directory, so when using pip install . only the basic version module should be installed, namely only installing foo_tool. When using pip install .[extension] an additional module should be installed, foo_tool_extension.
My Problem:
When running pip install . I want only the foo_tool module to be installed. When running pip install .[extension] I want the additional foo_tool_extension module to be installed. However, depending on my pyproject.toml configuration:

Both foo_tool and foo_tool_extension get installed, regardless of whether I specify the [extension] option.
Only the dist-info file is installed, but neither of the modules (foo_tool or foo_tool_extension) are installed.

c:\users\thetelefone\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\foo_tool-0.6.dist-info\*
c:\users\thetelefone\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\foo_tool\*
c:\users\thetelefone\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\foo_tool_extension\*

or only
c:\users\thetelefone\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\foo_tool-0.6.dist-info\*

with both modules missing.
My structure has the following layout:
/foo_project
├── src
│   ├── foo_tool
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── foo_problem.py
│   │   ├── foo_plotting.py
│   ├── foo_tool_extension
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── foo_problem_extension.py
├── tests
│   ├── ...
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml

Both __init__.py files are empty. Currently my pyproject.toml looks like the following. I tried several different options, but always resulting in the behavior above.
[project]
name = "foo_tool"
version = "0.6"
authors = [{name = "thetelefonecopmpany"}]
description = "Foo-Tool for fools."
requires-python = ">3.6"
dependencies = [
    "matplotlib",
    "pandas",
    "numpy",
    "openpyxl"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
exclude = ["foo_tool_extension"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
extension = [
    "scipy>=1.7.0",
    "foo_tool_extension @ file://src/foo_tool_extension"
]


How can I configure my pyproject.toml file to achieve this behavior?
Please also help me to improve this question. Thanks in advance!

You cannot do that. pip always installs a distribution as a whole, no conditional or optional submodules. You need to split your package into two separate distributions and declare foo_tool_extension as an optional dependency of foo_tool.

Look up the difference between an "import package" and a "distribution package": https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/distribution-package-vs-import-package/#distribution-package-vs-import-package. When we install things, we deal with distribution packages. If we want to have two import packages installable independently from each other, then these two import packages must be placed in two different distribution packages.
